# C# - Copy File to new location, then read in PDF (With Code)

Tags: c#, pdf

In the code below, the console prompts the user for 2 files (currently in a networked location).  It then copies those files to the local drive for quicker reading of the PDF, but I'm running into a problem.  If I reference the last line of code as PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument("C:\somepdf.pdf"); the file is accessed extremely quickly.

However, with the current copy processes, for some reason, this line of code alone is taking upwards of 18-20 minutes to process.  I'm assuming that this is because the file, having recently been copied, is still locked under a process, even though the actual copy process takes less than 10 seconds.

In my research, I have seen various ways of identifying the process that's locking the file and killing it, but this doesn't seem to apply to what I'm trying to do.

Unfortunately, I'm to the point where I have to ask for help.  Am I overlooking something here?  I don't see why it would take 15 less minutes to process a pdf referenced locally, than one processed by a copy process, then locally.

Thoughts?

```
string selectFileNameO;
string selectFileNameF;
string FileNameO;
string FileNameF;
using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    dialog.Title = "Choose File";
    dialog.FileName = "";
    dialog.ShowDialog();
    selectFileNameO = dialog.FileName;
}

string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(selectFileNameO);
selectFileNameF = Path.GetFileName(selectFileNameO);
selectFileNameF = selectFileNameF.Substring(0, selectFileNameF.Length - ext.Length);
selectFileNameF = "C:\\" + selectFileNameF + ".ext";

Console.WriteLine(selectFileNameF);

using (OpenFileDialog dialog2 = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    dialog2.Title = "Choose 2  File";
    dialog2.FileName = "";
    dialog2.ShowDialog();
    FileNameO = dialog2.FileName;
}

string ext1 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileNameO);
FileNameF = Path.GetFileName(FileNameO);
FileNameF = FileNameF.Substring(0, FileNameF.Length - ext1.Length);
FileNameF = "C:\\" + FileNameF + ".ext";

File.Copy(FileNameO, FileNameF, true);

int distanceToString = 535;
int lengthOfString = 6;
string myDataSet;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(selectFileNameF))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        myDataSet = line.Substring(distanceToString, lengthOfString);
        selectFileUIDs.Add(myDataSet);
        Console.WriteLine(myDataSet);
    }
    sr.Dispose();
}
Console.WriteLine(FileNameF);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(FileNameF);
```

Comment: Not related but `selectFileNameF = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(selectFileNameO);` could be used instead of that string trim

Comment: Where exactly is the time spent?

Comment: Perhaps unrelated. The file you select in the first dialog is never copied. `selectFilenameF` apparently refers to a file that's already on your local system?

Comment: While re-inventing the wheel is a bad idea, just to verify your assumption of file being locked by the copy process, why not write your own routine to copy the file across and replace File.Copy. Open the source as a binary stream and copy to a second binary stream (the target) once the process is done, properly close the streams. This should drop any locks on the newly created target

Comment: @jim - I must have deleted that line when I removed comments.  That file is inconsequential though, it's only 15k at the most and I have no problems with the speed in processing that one.

Comment: @ chintana - I have no clue how I would even begin to go about that.  It's been a few years since I was doing programming on a regular basis, and this is the first one I've done to knock the cobwebs off.

Comment: @magnus - What do you mean?  The last line of code in that snippet is the one that the program hangs on, if that's what you're asking.